# Footnote not rendering bib item

Tags: biblatex

I created a .bib file for my footnotes and bibliography but everytime I want to cite an item in the footnote the bibliographic information is not rendered, only the key.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={1in},vmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{diss.bib}


\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Palaeographical Profile}

\section*{Introduction}
Blah blah

\section*{Style of the Hand}
MOre blah blah Bob Lob Law\footcite{metzger2005text}

\end{document}
```

The following is my .bib file:

```
@book{metzger2005text,
  title={The text of the New Testament: its transmission, corruption, and restoration},
  author={Metzger, Bruce Manning and Ehrman, Bart D},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

Comment: have you run biber to generate the bibliography?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number/63875#63875

Comment: I did. But it says it cannot find the file. So, do I need to manually tell the engine where the file is? Or, do I need to put the file in the same folder as my .tex document?

Comment: You could have said that in the question:-) if biber didn't generate the bibliography, there are no bibliography items for latex to reference. `\addbibresource{diss.bib}` means the bib file is in the same directory, you can put a full path to the file if it is somewhere else, or copy the bib file there.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Im trying to do the following: \addbibresource{C:Users\Carlos Carrera\G-Diss\Dissertation\DissTeX\diss.bib}. To no avail.

Comment: Dot not use absolute paths like `C:/Users/etc`  but relative paths the to the main tex file (e.g. `../DisTeX/diss.bib`) and remember that life is easier without spaces in directory and file names. Note also that I typed  / instead of \ in the paths.

Comment: start simplest and put the bib file next to your document

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will.

Comment: In the test document that I sent you, you can see how I handled the relative paths to the bib and style files. You can do something similar.